# Recorded test plan does not work

Tags: forms, post, jmeter, performance-testing

I use jmeter to record the requests and then perform a performance test.

After I've recorded all the requests with proxy server and they contain post form,
I run these test-cases, but I found the post form not work: it can not create a record in website's database automatically.

But before that i used webload and everything was ok.

What's the problem? What can i do to solve it?

Comment: My crystal ball is currently not working fine, could you please add some details about *"the post form not work"*, an error trace or any other things that may help to understand the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Does your JMeter test contain an HTTP cookie manager?

Comment: Yes.  If your using Session, the HTTP cookie manager will persist the cookie between each sample for the same thread.  Think of JMeter as the ultimate incognito browser -it does nothing by default between each http request.

Answer (score 1):

The built in proxy recorder of JMeter may create problems in case your application requires cookies and/or sessions to allow access to content.

You might want to try **Blazemeter**. Blazemeter has an extension in Google Chrome. You can record your test script using this extension as you browse through your application. Once you are done, export the test script in `.JMX` format from the extension (you will have to be logged in to Blazemeter for this). Open that as test plan in JMeter. Make any changes required in the test plan and run your test!